# For how many real numbers 'b', does $x^2 + bx + 6b = 0$ have one integral root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

The question states.
For how many real numbers 'b', does $ f(x) =x^2 + bx + 6b = 0$ have one integral root ?
My line of thinking :
Let $\alpha  , \beta$ be the roots of of $f(x)$.
$\alpha + \beta = -b.   $
$\alpha\beta = 6b.   $
How to proceed ?
A hint would also suffice.

Comment: What is "integral root"?

Comment: @StAKmod A root which is an integer.

Comment: Do you mean _exactly_ one integral root, or _at least_ one integral root?

Comment: The language of the question does not confirm only one integral root. I think we should consider both cases : one integer or both integers.

Comment: @Arthur Ah,I thought that is another "integral"

Comment: $0$ and $24$ will work, not sure about other solutions

Comment: $\alpha \beta = -6 (\alpha + \beta)$ which will allow you to solve for $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$.

Comment: You mean one integral root and one non-integral root, right?

Comment: @TonyK Well, there are a couple cases where it has an integer as a double root and those could potentially count as degenerate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic has exactly one root if $b^2 - 24b = 0$

And it will be an integer if $b$ is even.

That is the easy part.

Suppose one root is an integer and one is not.

$6b = \alpha\beta\\
b = \frac {\alpha\beta}{6}\\
\alpha + \beta = - \frac {\alpha\beta}{6} \\
\alpha (6+\beta) = -6\beta\\
\alpha = \frac {-6\beta}{6+\beta}$

And now we can choose any integer value for $\beta$, and find a corresponding $\alpha$

$b = \frac{-\beta^2}{6+\beta}$

And this should work for any integer $\beta$